# Getting a substring of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, substring

I want to go through an `int[]` array and get substring values from it. For example if my array is `{1,2,1,4}` I want to be able to pull out the `{1,2}` and compare it to `{1,4}` or I want to pull out `{1,2,1}` and compare it to the `{4,1,2}`. My problem is that I want to go through an array and see if the "substring" values are again shown in the array but in reverse order.

I know for strings you have substring(inclusive, exclusive) is there anything similar for an array or do I have to convert the array to a string in order to do such a thing?

Comment: what do you mean by "reverse" order? why comparing `{1, 2, 1}` with `{4, 1, 2}` and how? Please share more examples with clear requirement and understanding.

Comment: `java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange` (specialized for each primitive element type or Object) gives a portion, in the same order, like String.substring. AFAICT there is no direct way to reverse an array.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply identify the number set and location form within the array that you wish to use and then start from the next index and search for the first or last number in your sequence and then once you find it then begin to search for the next number?

Ie [1, 4, 5, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2] where we want to take [1, 4] and find it's reverse in the array.

Starting from index 2: [5] != 1 -> [1] == 1 -> [3] != 4 -> [3] != 1 -> [1] == 1 -> [4] == 4, success.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare each number in the array with the last num of ur set, if they match then go into a loop which checks if the next number is the same the last but one number of ur set and so on.
Else come out of the loop and say no matches.

```
                                       Or
```

You can traverse in the reverse order in the given array to check for your set.
Might be a bit lengthy but works fine for all.

Answer (score 0):

If the String representation is not needed for something else you can (and should probably) just use the numbers in the array.

This is function that checks the symmetry of an interval in an int array. You could change the params for ini, end instead of ini, length if you prefer, change the arithmetics accordingly, of course.

```
public boolean checkSymmetry(int[] data, int ini, int length) {
    // Iterates the interval of interest
    for (int i=ini; i<ini+length-1; i++) {
        // The symmetric position: start from the end (length),
        // come back i positions and sum one (because arrays starts on 0)
        int symmetricPos = data.length - i - 1;
        if (data[i] != data[symmetricPos]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert integer array into a string however, `Arrays.toString()` function converts it literally. By that, from being `{1, 2, 2, 1}` to `[1, 2, 2, 1]`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) for more information.

```
// strTest -> [1, 2, 2, 1]
String strTest = Arrays.toString(test);
```

However, you can remove square brackets, commas, and spaces. By using `String.replace()` or `String.replaceAll()` functions. From `[1, 2, 2, 1]` to `1221`.

```
// strTest -> 1221
strTest = strTest.replaceAll(", ", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

If you want to reverse the existing string, you can use `StringBuffer.reverse()` function.

```
// use StringBuffer to acquire reverse of text
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(strTest.substring(2, 4)); // it will get '21' of '1221'
String revStrTest = buffer.reverse().toString(); // from '21' to '12'
```

Here is the full code:

```
// from array of test
int[] test = { 1, 2, 2, 1};

// strTest -> [1, 2, 2, 1]
String strTest = Arrays.toString(test);

// strTest -> 1221
strTest = strTest.replaceAll(", ", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

System.out.print(strTest.substring(0, 2) + " == " + strTest.substring(2, 4) + " : ");

// checks 12 and 21
if(strTest.substring(0, 2).equals(strTest.substring(2, 4)))
    System.out.println("EQUAL");
else
    System.out.println("NOT EQUAL");

// use StringBuffer to acquire reverse of text
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(strTest.substring(2, 4)); // it will get '21' of '1221'
String revStrTest = buffer.reverse().toString(); // from '21' to '12'

System.out.print(strTest.substring(0, 2) + " == " + revStrTest + " : ");

// checks 12 of strTest and 12 of revStrTest
if(strTest.substring(0, 2).equals(revStrTest))
    System.out.println("EQUAL");
else
    System.out.println("NOT EQUAL");
```